# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x... for fragment

Tags: android, exception, view

I get this error from time to time:

```
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b00d5 for fragment FragmentSettingsDetailDevice{424cf258 #1 id=0x7f0b00d5}
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:823)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:637)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-16 14:29:35.675: E/AndroidRuntime(15617):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The view does exist in both layout and layout-land - the error is intermittent.

Why would I ever get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the view at id "X" isn't found, this leads me to assume that your id is off. This can happen if you edit your layouts but don't rebuild your project. The R class in Android works to maintain static integers that point to each id you declare in source. If you then change the source, but R isn't updated, then you will see this error. The best way I have found to avoid this is that any time I edit a /res file, I always do a clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this layout has not changed for some time.